# Rails & Heroku: Running a script through rails runner using local files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So, I have an app deployed on Heroku, and I'm trying to populate the database on the app through a script I wrote. I have the database in a text file, and the script runs through the file and populates the database. I don't want to push the database file to the heroku server, since it's a very large file.

Is there any way to do this on Heroku? It works fine locally, but I can't get it to work on the Heroku server.

I've tried

```
 heroku run rails runner PATH/TO/SCRIPT LOCAL/PATH/TO/DATABASE --app my_app
```

to no avail.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I believe I just put the file in the /scripts or /lib folder, though I'm not 100% sure if that is what I did.

Answer (score 0):

To run a local script on Heroku:

```
irbify.rb script.rb | heroku run rails console --app=my_app
```

[irbify.rb](https://gist.github.com/tadas-s/6537653#file-irbify-rb) is a silly tiny script I wrote to convert a script to a single eval statement.

Regarding passing data: you can serialize it in some form and put it inside script.

Hope it helps someone.

UPDATE: this does not work well anything beyond trivial datasets.

Answer (score 0):

You can also upload your script to a gist and then do:

```rb
binding.eval(open("your gist raw url").read)
```

I had to use global variables (`$dollar_prefixed`) since the context would not get filled with the variables (using Pry), otherwise it went well.